# Is there a way to disable built-in simulated monitor on motherboard designed for signage?

Tags: display, bios, motherboard

I haven't been able to find any documentation on it, and have spent hours scouring its BIOS, with no luck. It seems to be sold by multiple companies, with no additional information.

I bought it to be able to reuse a socketed mobile processor, and it otherwise seems to work great, but it has pinouts for directly driving an LCD, and so it has a "monitor" show up in any OS as the primary, making it a massive pain to get through initial login and stuff since everything renders on a monitor I can't see.

I don't know what I'm looking for, but I'm hoping maybe there's some way around it I haven't thought of.

This is one of the only places I can find the exact same one still listed with pictures like [this one](https://www.amazon.ae/dp/B07Z525S6R).

It's marked as a Jingsha HM55 Motherboard (PGA988), but it looks like they're selling another model under that model number now that something closer to a full ATX board, so the listing helps clarify.

By simulated monitor, I mean the motherboard presents a monitor to the operating system (presumably via either a dedicated chip somewhere or maybe the BIOS is doing it) in order to drive its `18/24-bit Dual Channel LVDS` as the listing describes it, which would usually be used to directly drive an LCD panel, it's like it has a display driver-board built into it, but I have no way to use that and need to figure out a way to turn it off/disconnect it somehow.

Comment: it sounds like you are working with a rather specialized device, and it may be hard for other members to understand what you mean by "simulated monitor" in relation to a motherboard. it may be a good idea to explain it as you would to someone who is unfamilliar with your usecase. at a mininum the make and model of the motherboard may help.

Comment: Updated it some. Was able to research a little more about what it specifies as an LVDS connection, but it's a generic interconnect that "can" be used to drive a display, so it seems to have a built-in display panel driver-board, but I'm no closer to figuring out how to disable it.

Answer (score 2):

I also recently bought a similar Chinese industrial motherboard with LVDS output.

I was unable to disable the LVDS in the BIOS, but found some interesting settings at:
Chipset -> System Agent (SA) Configuration -> Graphics -> LCD Control

If you're lucky, "No LVDS" is an option for the "Active LFP" setting, which may disable it.

However, in my case, the only thing that stopped the OS from seeing the display was to remove jumpers on two headers labelled "LVDS_1" and "LVDS_2".

The pictures you've sent aren't high enough resolution, but there may be similar jumpers to disable LVDS on your board.

[image: Motherboard close-up]